# After downloading swagger.net to web Api project I get error as Assembly generation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I have installed SwaggerUI for .Net from Nuget package and trying to test web api methods with the swagger. But I am get below compile time error.

```
Error   Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'WebActivator' does not have a strong name
```

When I change the solution settings for **signing**  property from checked to unchecked I don't get this error. Now I don't want to change any settings that are made to signing property of solution settings and fix this error.Can any one please help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your assemblies are strong named while the new assemblies you referenced recently are not. And more than this, they are not compiled from source (you got them via NuGet).

Two workarounds cross my mind now:

1. Get the sources for SwaggerUI and dependecies and sign them with your key. I think this is a tedious process, since you need to build everything.
2. Use the DLLs like now and sign them **after each build**. For example you can use [these instructions](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx) (dissasemble, sign & re-assemble). If you do this, I think it's worth adding this as a pre-build step to your least-dependent project (the one that builds first).
3. I have also found this - [Assembly Strong Naming Toolkit (for NuGet)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.StrongNaming/). Never tried, but maybe it's worth looking into as it seems to be designed for your case.